# How would I go about creating a flow chart representing a linux grep command?

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, cat

I am currently using the Linux terminal and command:

```
cat [filename] | grep [searchword]
```

To search a file contents for a specific word/string, but how would i represent this command within a flow chart? Would I use a parallelogram shape to show an input of the cat output into the grep command?
Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question about the flowchart is vague. Use a pointer? Anyhow. The command should definitely look like:

```
grep [searchword] [filename]
```

Read:

- [Useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)
- [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html)

Answer (score 0):

A square with "cat [filename]" and a square with "grep [searchword]", with an arrow between going from the first square to the second square…

Why would you want to do that?

And yes, you don't need to "pipe" a cat and a grep, as grep is made to take the first argument as searchword and the second argument as the file to search in.

This is a very common error (while it still works well… that's just performance and readabilty considerations…). I suppose because it's a simple and didactic, often used, exemple on how to use "pipes"…